I need help to prove that :$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k}\frac{(2n-k)!n!}{(2n)!(n-k)!}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}$
I need help to prove that :
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}}{k}
\frac{\left(2n-k\right)!\,n!}
{\left(2n\right)!\,\left(n - k\right)!} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k - 1}
$$
I tried all the tricks I know, but they don't work. It took me a long time trying to find the solution (for more than 4 hours).
My idea
Let
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k}\frac{(2n-k)!n!}{(2n)!(n-k)!}$$
It suffices to prove that $S_{n+1}-S_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}$
I tried to prove this as well, and it started to get more and more complicated.

The fractions of factorials look like you could try rewriting it as certain binomial coefficients. I haven't tried it however; just an idea...

I don't know if this can help: multiply and divide by $k!$ to get $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k}\frac{(2n-k)!n!}{(2n)!(n-k)!} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)!!}{k} \frac{(2n-k)!}{(2n)!}\binom{n}{k} $$

Please add your workings as the question has already received close votes.

An idea that comes to my mind is to write the factorials as Gamma functions and since you'll have quotients of those, then maybe it is possible to write it as a Beta function and use its integral expression. Solving such integral might simplify numerators and denominators, but it's just a hunch...

We seek to show that
$${2n\choose n}^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k} {2n-k\choose n-k}
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}.$$
Working with the binomial coefficient in the sum on the LHS we get
$$\frac{(2n)^{\underline n}}{(2n)^{\underline k}}
\frac{1}{(n-k)!}
= {2n\choose n} {n\choose k} {2n\choose k}^{-1}$$
and hence we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} \frac{2^k}{k}
{2n\choose k}^{-1}.$$
Recall from MSE
4316307  the
following identity which was proved there: with $1\le k\le n$
$$\frac{1}{k} {n\choose k}^{-1}
= [v^n] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{n-k}.$$
Apply to our sum to get
$$[v^{2n}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{2n}
\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} 2^k (v-1)^{-k}.$$
Here we get two pieces, the first is
$$- [v^{2n}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{2n}
= - \sum_{q=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^q}{q} {2n\choose q}.$$
and the second
$$[v^{2n}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{2n}
\left[1+\frac{2}{v-1}\right]^n
\\ = [v^{2n}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{n} (v+1)^n
= \sum_{q=1}^n \frac{(-1)^q}{2q} {n\choose q}.$$
 Sum with two instances appearing 
We clearly require
$$\sum_{q=1}^m \frac{(-1)^q}{q} {m\choose q}.$$
With this in mind we introduce
$$f(z) = (-1)^m m! \frac{1}{z} \prod_{r=0}^m \frac{1}{z-r}.$$
which has the property that for $1\le q\le m$
$$\;\underset{z=q}{\mathrm{res}}\; f(z)
= (-1)^m m! \frac{1}{q} \prod_{r=0}^{q-1} \frac{1}{q-r}
\prod_{r=q+1}^m \frac{1}{q-r}
\\ = (-1)^m m! \frac{1}{q} \frac{1}{q!} \frac{(-1)^{m-q}}{(m-q)!}
= \frac{(-1)^q}{q} {m\choose q}.$$
With the residue at infinity being zero we have that our desired
sum is contribution from minus the residue at zero, which gives
$$(-1)^m m! \left. \prod_{r=1}^m \frac{1}{z-r}
\sum_{r=1}^m \frac{1}{r-z} \right|_{z=0}
= -H_m.$$
 Collecting the pieces 
Apply to the two pieces to get
$$\frac{1}{2} (-H_n) + H_{2n}
= - \sum_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{2q} + \sum_{q=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{q}
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}.$$
This is the claim and we may conclude.

Very nice solution. (+1)

A partial answer
$$\begin{gather*}
S_{n+1} - S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}{k}\frac{(2n+2-k)!(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!(n-k+1)!} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k}\frac{(2n-k)!n!}{(2n)!(n-k)!} \\
= \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{(2n+2-n-1)!(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!(n-n-1+1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k}\frac{(2n-k)!n!}{(2n)!(n-k)!} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k}\frac{(2n-k)!n!}{(2n)!(n-k)!} \\
= \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!}
\end{gather*} $$
Now we will split this into two cases: one for $n$ odd, and one for $n$ even.
Case 1: $n = 2j-1, \ \ \ j \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{gather*} 
\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!} \\
= \frac{2^{2j}}{2j}\frac{(2j)!(2j)!}{(4j)!} \\
= \frac{(4j)!!}{(4j)!} \cdot (2j-1)! \\
= \frac{(2j-1)!}{(4j-1)!!} \\ \\
= \frac{(2j-1)!}{\frac{(4j-1)!}{2^{2j-1} (2j-1)!}}
\end{gather*}$$
Sadly I am unable to simplify further, if someone sees something, please do edit this answer and add it! I tried using the product definitions, but in my rough I couldn't come up with anything :|
Case 2: $n = 2j, \ \ \ j \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{gather*} 
\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!} \\
= \frac{2^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\frac{(2j+1)!(2j+1)!}{(4j+2)!} \\
= 2 \cdot (4j)!! \cdot \frac{(2j+1)!}{(4j+2)!}
\end{gather*}$$
This case is tougher. I can't think of anything that might simplify this either.
